# Can't access Jenkins running on ec2-instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

I've tried setting up jenkins on some free-tier ec2 instances (I've tried ubuntu based and Amazon's own AMI) and despite jenkins running properly I can't access it on port 8080 using browser no matter what I try.

I've check that jenkins is running both by running sudo service jenkins status and by running curl localhost:8080 once I'm ssh'd in.

I've tried all the answers to similar questions on the web but nothing has worked. I've set up my security group exactly as all guides online state for installing jenkins on ec2 , I even went really overboard and made it overly open - nothing!
Note - I've not tried setting it up behind apache/nginx but I'm feeling I shouldn't have to out of the principle that it should work on 8080

UPDATE - I caved and tried to setup Nginx using this link https://markunsworth.com/2012/02/11/setting-up-a-jenkins-build-server-on-ec2/ . I get the standard nginx welcome screen - it doesn't serve up jenkins for me

[My overly open security group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Zz4n.jpg)

Any help would be hugely appreciated

Comment: try to access without the port:
http://ec2-XX-XX-XX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com/

Comment: Have you tried to restart the service? It started to work after I restart the process

Comment: I have a similar problem... I have configured the security group and Jenkins is running on my EC2 instance but from my PC it is not accessible. @Dilsk have you found something?

Answer (score 4):

**You need to open 8080 port in AWS.**

Check this to do it: https://hayato-iriumi.net/2019/08/22/how-to-install-jenkins-on-aws/

After that you 're good to go by using the public IP of the EC2 and port 8080 :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have faced similar issue in the Windows Ec2. Configured the inbound Security group and setup Custom TCP >> Protocol: TCP >> Port Range: 8080>>Source: Custom 0.0.0.0/0 .
Accessed URL from browser http://url:8080, couldn't access the Jenkins.

Later in Ec2 under Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Defender Firewall >> Advanced Setting
Configured the New Inbound rules for 8080 port resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure open 8080 port on aws console, while accessing url from browser, by default it use https://* , try to access with http.

Answer (score 0):

Try this steps it work for me

sudo yum update –y

sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo 
https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.repo

sudo rpm --import https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io.key

sudo yum upgrade

sudo yum install jenkins java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel -y

sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo systemctl start jenkins

sudo systemctl status jenkins

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem. To check if your Jenkins is running, you can try `ps aux | grep jenkins`

In my case, I was running Tomcat at port 8080, when I try that command, it shows nothing

[image]

Then I changed my Tomcat port and restart Jenkins by using

```
sudo systemctl stop jenkins
sudo systemctl start jenkins
```

and when I check Jenkins again, it was fine.

[image]

There, you can see that the port that Jenkins is using is `8080`. To change the port, you can try `sudo vi /etc/sysconfig/jenkins` and look for `JENKINS_PORT`

If you config it right, you will see something like this

[image]

To summarize:

1. Check Jenkins status
2. Check Jenkins port
3. Allow the Jenkins port on security group

Comment: To whoever voted down: please give me the reason why I got voted down when I was trying to help with the answer and also the proved that the solution works.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who is facing problem please make sure that your java path is correct in
Windows firewall -> Inbound rule -> Jenkins right click and go to properties then program and services select your java path by browsing. I was allow to access from outside EC2 once I setup java path properly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Go to the inbound tab of the Security group and do the below thing.

Type: Custom TCP

Protocol: TCP

Port Range: 8080

Source: Custom 0.0.0.0/0

Answer (score 0):

Visit https://www.jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/tutorial-for-installing-jenkins-on-AWS/

Follow the steps to create under **Creating a security group**

Then follow 5th step under **Launching an Amazon EC2 instance**

If you have already created the instance then click on that instace from instances dashboard  then open Action dropdown -> Security -> Change security groups

Remove the default security group from the **Security groups associated** table this enables "Add security group" button

Then search for the newly created security group and select it. Then click on save button.

you should be able to access jenkins from http://<your_EC2_public_DNS>:8080

Answer (score -1):

In my case none of above solutions helped and in the end it was just overlooked "s" in http**s**://instance-url:8080

when I deleted it and used http://instance-url:8080 it worked